# how to add floating over lay screen from left to right on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

The goal is to have layover coming from left to right by hiding all components.

Comment: The problem is on line 17.

Comment: Please may you show, and not tell, us what's wrong? Edit the question to include a [mcve], otherwise we're left guessing

Comment: Welcome to SO-- I recommend new users review [ask] for tips on forming their questions in a way that best enables the community to help them.  In this case, we need to see a [mcve] of what you've done, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @AlexanderNied Unfortunately, this user isn't new. They've been a member for 4 years!

Comment: Why has the question been changed to match the answer below?

Comment: @ScottMarcus - true.  To be fair, this is the first question that they have submitted, although I get your point that one would expect them be aware of the site format by this point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let drawerName = 'sideNav';
const drawerWidth = {
  expanded: '100%',
  collapsed: '0%'
};

openDrawer = () => setWidth(drawerWidth.expanded);
closeDrawer = () => setWidth(drawerWidth.collapsed);

function setWidth(width) {
  document.getElementById(drawerName).style.width = width;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(5, 3, 119);
  background-color: rgba(63, 48, 204, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #ebebeb;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="sideNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeDrawer()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openDrawer()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Please check it out. Seems like something you are looking for.

Comment: sorry... how does this answer the question? The OP seems to be looking for fireworks to be overlaid on top of a webpage. I don't think a "burger nav" helps here.

Comment: We tend not to post answers to poor questions that should not be here in the first place as it just encourages more poor questions. Also, given that the OP has not shown any code, your answer is not really an "answer". It's just a demo of a technique.

Comment: I was adding the answers for a little while. BTW, the question got modified. @ScottMarcus

Comment: @jithil how did you manage to answer the "left-to-right overlay" question before it was edited?

Comment: I don't even understand what *I was adding the answers for a little while.* means. And, neither the original version of the question or this current version are questions that warrant an answer here. In fact, after the edit, it's even worse than before.